# What are the fundamental limits of very tiny radios?

Tags: radio

For a [hard SF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_sf) story, I'm wondering about the physical limits of communications devices in a micro robot, say, the size of a mosquito. Figure one microgram mass.

Real technology has [already come a long way](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Earbabian/Home/IoT_Radio.html) since stories on this subject such as Hogan's *Bug Park*.

Assuming no limits on technology, but still made of atoms and employing the known laws of physics, what are some *fundamental limits* of making machines this small be able to communicate?

This includes limited availability of

- mass (1 or 2 µg)
- length/area (2.5mm body length; appendages could fold out to form an antenna)
- power (chemical power from sugar and ambient oxygen)

It appears that a short range link with a special (large, powerful) docking station is not a problem. But what about longer range communications between such micro machines?

I recall a new article where a FM radio was built using a single nanotube. So I assume that receiving a sufficiently strong signal requires only a few atoms. But transmitting, and receiving the signal strength a peer can transmit, will have some hard limits that will find this scale challenging.

Comment: The prominence of swarm intelligence makes this question relevant and fascinating. As to answering it ... I imagine the first step is to determine the available average power and then do speculative engineering.